# When dissolving natural organic yeast in water, is it supposed to bubble?

Tags: baking, dough, yeast

When I made a dough, I dissolved natural organic yeast in water, but it didn’t make bubbles. Is this a sign that something is wrong?

Comment: Did you mix the dissolved yeast into the dough, and it is not bubbling?  or is it just yeast and water?  I've never found just yeast-and-water to show bubbles, the yeasties need a bit of food (a sprinkle of sugar or something) and a bit of time before I see activity... and even then it can be subtle

Comment: And are we talking about dry yeast or fresh?

Comment: It’s dry have bought from amazon, when I put it in water ..it doesn’t bubbles then I add vinegar, it doesn’t bubbles then I add sugar.. also doesn’t bubbles

Comment: Forget the vinegar. Add a little sugar. Good yeast should bubble wohin 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you're adding the dry yeast powder to water. The yeast typically won't bubble or do much of anything else at this phase.

Yeast are microscopic organisms that produce gas by consuming sugars and excreting carbon dioxide. This requires that they have sugar to eat, which plain water of course doesn't. The main purpose of water is to rehydrate the yeast and revive them from their dried state.

Once you mix the yeast into a dough (which does contain sugars in flour that the yeast can consume) they'll start producing gas, but this isn't a fast process. You may not even see visible bubbles, just the end result as your dough rises over the course of hours.

So there's not yet any indication of problems with your yeast. If you have issues once they're mixed into the dough, there are many skilled bakers here who can provide diagnosis.

Comment: I'm also suggesting to add something very important: *do not mix vinegar with yeast solution*. It kills the poor things.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yeast is perishable. Typical instructions for testing yeast (active dry or cake, but NOT for instant yeast) include adding the packet (typically @ 2 tsp/ 7 g) yeast and 1 tbsp. granulated sugar to 1/2 cup / 113 ml (warm to very warm water (100-120ºF / 40-48ºc) and and letting it sit for about 10 minutes. It won't necessarily bubble up dramatically but if it is still live yeast it should form a bubbly foam on top. If your yeast foams up you can immediately use it in your baking recipe. If it does not foam up it is likely too old (dead). Try again with warm water and sugar. And *do not* add vinegar.

Adding the vinegar is likely the cause for the yeast not bubbling, as the acid in vinegar inhibits the yeast. While it can be useful in baking to slow down the fermentation and help the bread's gluten (and flavor) develop over a longer rise time, it's not good for testing your yeast. (and the longer rise can be achieved by refrigerating the dough while it's rising, to the same effect).

Comment: I really appreciate ur reply do u have an idea how to make fresh yeast